# Laravel : Not able to decode a string which seems JSON in controller : No exception either

Tags: php, json, laravel

When I print the \Input:all() I get this in the laravel.log :

```
        Input :  {"val":{"postID":"22","tags":["3"],"forwardComment":"aaaaaaa"}} []
```

It seems JSON, so I've tried this, but it fails silently and doesn't even throw an exception.

```
        $input = \Input::all();

        Log::info('Input : ', $input);
        try
        {
            $decodedArray = json_decode($input, true);
            Log::info('After decoding'); // This isn't in the logs either
            //var_dump($obj);
            Log::info('$decodedArray[val][forwardComment] : ', $decodedArray['val']['forwardComment']);
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            Log::info('*** Exception : ', $e->getMessage());
        }
```

From what I understand, json_decode(string, true) will convert the object into an array.

I also tried the Laravel way, but that didn't work either, what's confounding is that there is no stack trace in laravel.log ! Why..
Here are the things I tried from [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests) :

```
Log::info('input::get(val.forwardComment): ', \Input::get('val.0.forwardComment'));
Log::info('input::get(val.forwardComment): ', \Input::get('val.forwardComment'));
```

I tried with my sample program and it does work, but not sure why it isn't working in Laravel.
Here is my sample code which works for this string :

```
<?php
$str = '{"val":{"postID":"22","tags":["3"],"forwardComment":"aaaaaaa"}}';
$obj = json_decode($str, true);
var_dump($obj);
print $obj['val']['forwardComment'];
?>
```

Here is the view that calls the controller :

```
$.ajax({
            url : baseUrl + 'post/forward/' + postID,
            type : 'POST',
            data : new FormData(this),
            contentType : false,
            cache : false,
            processData : false,
            success : function(data) {
                console.log('Success function of the ajax call');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the json you are decoding is failing,try this:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    echo "JSON was valid";
} else {
    echo "In valid JSON"
}
```

If you get invalid, try sending a correct json format.

Use this: `$obj['val'][0]['forwardComment']`

Debug:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($decodedArray);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

See, if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't get past the json_decode statement. to reach json_last_error. Not having an exception stumps me..

Comment: Your JSON data is correct, there might be some issue with the code before json_decode statement

Comment: Adding the view - it's in an ajax call with data in FormData()

Comment: I just tried this and it worked : Log::info('Type : ', $input['val']); So it's not JSON, but I can't get to the inner values. The above sentence printed :  Type :  {"postID":"22","tags":["3"],"forwardComment":"aaaaaaa"} []

Comment: updated my answer, see if you get the desired output

Comment: Tried, didn't work.. My inputs are in the form of array, so in the html all fields sent back are name="val[postID]", name='val[forwardComment]' etc. hope that makes sense.

Comment: I have added a print_r function, attach the output in your question. Would help to trace array data

Comment: Why? you can yse it! else write a dummy route and call that function where your code is residing.